# Synchronize Databases, one in Django, one is a php sql, both hosted online

Tags: php, sql, django, database

I have 2 databases, one in the models of a Django server, the other is an sql with php. Is there any way to synchronize these 2 databases ?
Or at least a few fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but Django offers the `inspectdb` option, which will try to integrate with an existing database.

There is an [official howto available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/).

Once you run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`, you'll likely want to adjust, or at least thoroughly review, before issuing the `migrate` command.

Comment: The other database is on a different server. Not local

Comment: @MeghdeepRay: that doesn't matter, `inspectdb` works on both local and remote servers.